# Differentiating Between Virtual (Robot) and Physical KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot

I'm wondering if there's a decent method of differentiating between virtual (from AWT's Robot) and physical sources of KeyEvent objects?

I'm making a virtual keyboard, but would like the keyboard to disappear when/if the user uses a physical keyboard.

Below is an example that illustrates the problem I need to get around (while ignoring the other fluff of implementing an actual virtual keyboard).  I'm trying to fix the if/else statement below the FIXME line (I realize that the logic there is not correct).

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RobotTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new RobotTest();
    }

    public RobotTest()
    {
        // Create a "virtual keyboard"
        MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
        window.setVisible( true );

        // Event listener to differentiate between virtual and physical key events.
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched( final AWTEvent e )
            {
                if (( e instanceof KeyEvent )
                        && ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                        && ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    // FIXME: BELOW IS GUARANTEED FALSE
                    if ( ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getSource() instanceof Robot)
                    {
                        System.out.println("FROM ROBOT");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("FROM KEYBOARD");
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    // prototype keyboard with an "A" key.
    private class MyWindow extends JFrame
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            content.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            // Button that emulates pressing A
            JButton button = new JButton( "A" );
            button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Robot r = new Robot();
                        r.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_A );
                        r.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_A );
                    }
                    catch( AWTException ex )
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            content.add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            setContentPane( content );

            setSize(50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the perspective of Java, no, there is no difference or way to tell the difference

Comment: The entire point of java.awt.Robot is to use the actual OS input drivers to deliver events, to allow for low-level testing. So by definition, they *are* "real" key events.

Comment: I understand and suspected as much.  If it was any different, I can only assume there would've been a method put in the event to tell you the originator of the event.  I was more so wondering if anyone had any clever ideas around the problem, because, honestly, I'm at a loss.  Best thing I can come up with is to look at each key you plan to type with the robot, add it to a queue, and constantly dequeue elements in the listener.  If what you're trying to dequeue doesn't match what's in there, then an external event must've occurred.

Actually, after typing it out, I think I have my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the route I ended up going with isn't guaranteed to solve the general problem of determining if a KeyEvent came from the Robot or a physical source, but it lets me detect if there was any input outside of my robot.

I simply made a queue of expected events from the Robot.  Once an event is received, I check if the Robot had intended to press that key by polling the queue.  This is pretty much guaranteed to detect if there was a physical event, but, due to synchronicity issues, isn't guaranteed to find the source of the KeyEvent.  I've attached the (extremely simple) solution in case it's of use to anyone.

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RobotTest
{
    // CHANGE #1: store a queue of virtual key presses.
    public static Queue<Integer> robotKeys = new LinkedList<Integer>();


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new RobotTest();
    }


    public RobotTest()
    {
        // Create a "virtual keyboard"
        MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
        window.setVisible( true );

        // Event listener to differentiate between virtual and physical key events.
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched( final AWTEvent e )
            {
                if (( e instanceof KeyEvent )
                        && ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                        && ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    // CHANGE #2: check the received event against the front of the queue.
                    Integer expectedRobotKey = robotKeys.poll();
                    if (expectedRobotKey != null && expectedRobotKey == ( ( KeyEvent ) e ).getKeyCode())
                    {
                        System.out.println("No physical input detected.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Physical input detected.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    // prototype keyboard with an "A" key.
    private class MyWindow extends JFrame
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            content.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            // Button that emulates pressing A
            JButton button = new JButton( "A" );
            button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Robot r = new Robot();
                        // CHANGE #3: add events to the stored queue before sending them out.
                        robotKeys.add( KeyEvent.VK_A );
                        r.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_A );
                        r.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_A );
                    }
                    catch( AWTException ex )
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            content.add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            setContentPane( content );

            setSize(50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```